# Orientation of a best fit plane in 3D space

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, geometry

I'm looking at trying to obtain the Orientation of a plane that's plotted as a best fit line in a 3D scatter diagram using python 3.4.3 and Matplotlib. I currently have the data plotted in a 3D diagram with a plane going through the points and need a way to obtain the orientation of the plane.
Looking at getting the angle it is dipping at from the Z axis. Is there a shortcut i've missed that simply "prints" the orientation angle. Or would it be possible to create a trigonmetric feature from the roof of the box to the plane to get the angle. Also I have very little knowledge on mathplotlib therefore any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def plane(x, y, params):
    a = params[0]
    b = params[1]
    c = params[2]
    z = a*x + b*y + c
    return z

def error(params, points):
    result = 0
    for (x,y,z) in points:
        plane_z = plane(x, y, params)
        diff = abs(plane_z - z)
        result += diff**2
    return result

def cross(a, b):
    return [a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1],
            a[2]*b[0] - a[0]*b[2],
            a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]]

points = [(1.1,2.1,8.1),
          (3.2,4.2,8.0),
          (5.3,1.3,8.2),
          (3.4,2.4,8.3),
          (1.5,4.5,5.0)]

fun = functools.partial(error, points=points)
params0 = [0, 0, 0]
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, params0)

a = res.x[0]
b = res.x[1]
c = res.x[2]

xs, ys, zs = zip(*points)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs)

point  = np.array([0.0, 0.0, c])
normal = np.array(cross([1,0,a], [0,1,b]))
d = -point.dot(normal)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid([-5,10], [-5,10])
z = (-normal[0] * xx - normal[1] * yy - d) * 1. /normal[2]
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z, alpha=0.6, color=[1,1,0])

ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)
ax.set_zlim(0,10)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This sounds like a simple math question.  Do you know the equation of the plane, or 3 points that are actually on the plane?

Comment: No I don't have an output for the equation of the plane, although i'm sure theres a simple piece of code that will print that output. Do you have any ideas what it would be. Apologies in advance for my poor knowledge on this.

Comment: Is your question about how to fit a plane to the points, or do you already have a fit and you just want to compute its angle w.r.t. the z axis?

Comment: Yes I already have the plane @ali_m that's plotted as a best fit of my scatter points, so I'm simply trying to get the orientation of that plane in degrees as an output.

Comment: I'm a geologist and the best fit plane represents a structure that I need the dip of, to form a cross section. Because the orientation of that plane from the Z axis is how much a rock type is dipping.

Comment: What format is the fit in? Could you show your fitting code?

Comment: @ali_m i've added the code into the main question

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the posted code.

Comment: It look like `normal` is the normal to the optimzing plane.  Then you can get the angle from the third direction cosine.  Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly my knowlege of geometry you can calculate the angle with the z axis only by adding.

```
from math import acos, sqrt
cos_theta=1./sqrt(a*a+b*b+1)
theta=acos(cos_theta)
```

theta will be the angle between the vector normal to the plane and the z axis in radians. For example the XY plane have a theta of 0 and the ZY plane will have  theta of pi/2

Comment: Yes i've got it working now with the conversion to Radians! Thank you!